# OpenURI having issues when passed URLs with fragment identifiers

Tags: ruby, open-uri, fragment-identifier

I have a requirement to read a series of URLs from a text file and then retrieve the pages and output a list of links.

The code has issues whenever the input URLs contain fragment identifiers (`#`). I tried escaping these with `%23` but this didn't seem to help.

The error given is from OpenURI and is 404.

```
#requirements
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
#opening each line in input text file
line_num=0
text=File.open('input.txt').read
text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
text.each_line do |line|
    print "#{line_num += 1} #{line}"
    open('output.txt', 'a') { |f|
        f.puts "#{line_num} #{line}"
    }
    uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(line.strip))
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri))   
    links = page.css("div.product-carousel-container a")
    #loop through links if present
    e = 0
    while e < links.length
        open('output.txt', 'a') { |f|
        f.puts links[e]["href"]
        }
        e += 1
    end  
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't send a request with a fragment in them. Browsers strip those before sending the request.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with your code, especially one where it's with input data, we need the minimal example of the data that duplicates the problem in the question itself. While we can often cobble up something that reproduces the problem, doing so wastes our time and can possibly result in confusion or bad answers if the imagineered data isn't correct. So, we need you to provide it for us. It saves us time and helps us help you and helps anyone else searching for similar solutions decide if your question is a good match to their needs.

Comment: @ the Tin Man Noted with thanks. First question, so the next one will be phrased better. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Fragment part of a URI should not be sent to server.

From [Wikipedia: Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server — of course the server typically helps to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a web resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.

### Solution

Strip fragment part of a URI before passing it to `open`.

```
require "uri"

u = URI.parse "http://example.com#fragment"
u.fragment = nil
u.to_s #=> "http://example.com"
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use URI or Addressable::URI to manipulate URIs. While we can often make changes to URIs without the class, too often they need special encoding that gets missed, but the class automatically provides. Removing [a fragment](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-fragment-3D) is easy, just assign `nil` to it: `uri.fragment = nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You're 90% of the way there. The client is responsible for processing the fragment.

Your code is already using URI to parse the string, so let the parsed object remove the fragment:

```
require 'open-uri'
uri = URI.parse('http://foo.com/index.html#bar')
uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://foo.com/index.html#bar>
uri.fragment = nil
uri # => #<URI::HTTP http://foo.com/index.html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!